# Copy a variable with value in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, struct

I have a variable declared in this way

```
var model: cellModelCollection<AnyObject, collectionViewCell>
```

I want to create another variable *modelCopy* with the same values as model but if I delete an item from *modelCopy* I don't want it to be deleted from *model*.

`let modelCopy = model` don't work.

I also tried to create a struct  s

```
a.model = self.model
b.model = self.model
//delete an item from a.model
print (a.model.count) // 32
print (b.model.count) // 32  element also deleted from b
```

Comment: Please add code with `cellModelCollection` and `struct s` definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `cellModelCollection` should be of type *struct*, not *class*. **Structures are always copied when they are passed around in your code, and do not use reference counting.**
Check example below in storyboard. You will see that print will produce different results.

```
struct Model {
    var arg = [0, 1, 2]
}
struct Struct {
    var model: Model?
}

var myStruct1 = Struct()
var myStruct2 = Struct()
var myModel = Model()

myStruct1.model = myModel
myModel.arg.removeLast()
myStruct2.model = myModel

print(myStruct1.model!.arg)
print(myStruct2.model!.arg)
```

This gives result:

```
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1]
```

BUT if you change `struct Model` to `class Model` then result of printing will be the same:

```
[0, 1]
[0, 1]
```

Comment: Thanks but is there any other solution? For some reasons I can't change it to Struct.

Comment: Ok, if you can change Model, then you can write `init(model: Model)` or something similar, and copy everything.